# Weird [?] characters in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have created a private character using 'Private Character Editor' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Character_Editor).

Unfortunately, the character i have created does not display in Visual Studio, instead i get a 'question mark inside a square' character.
I can type the private character into notepad using Alt+57344, but that same key combination does not even register in Visual Studio. Interestingly, whilst notepad outputs the next private character if i type Alt+57345, Visual Studio output the same as Alt+1 ... awesome :)

How can i get the private character to display properly?

---

Update!

The private character displays happily in Word and Notepad, and also in a RichTextBox in my own application, but not in Excel (i just get a 'computer says no ding' when i try to use Alt+57344). I can however paste the character into Excel using Character Map.

Cheers.

Comment: Surely related to WPF.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: @HansPassant: Hi, How is this related to WPF? Does the Visual Studio IDE Text Editor use a WPF text box control?

Comment: I have posted on connect.ms.com ... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/749292/visual-studio-2010-does-not-display-private-characters